# Paging in nHibernate against SQL Server: Is a sort order required?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

We discovered that in our .NET 4.51/nHibernate/SQL 2008 app that when we do a single large query, we get all the data, but when we page against certain large results sets, rows are missed.

(In our testing, when we do pages of 200 per page, against a result set that is 1000 or more rows, we see the problem.)

We tried the app using the SQL2000 and SQL2005 nHibernate dialects, and saw no difference in behavior. (The query syntax does evolves to use newer constructs in SQL2005, but the same data is missing when using SQL2005 dialect.)

nHibernate generates SQL queries.
We are doing paging.
If we page by 100, the way nHibernate generates the successive SQL queries is:

- TOP 100  // gives us first 100
- TOP 200  // gives us 2nd 100 of this block
- etc

The above, without an ORDER BY / sorting at nHibernate level, has the end result that some rows never surface to nHibernate. We surmise this is due arbitrary sorting by SQL, so that rows are "moving around" within the pages (and thus "hide" from our application code).

If we do the nHibnerate query as a single shot (returning all rows), we see all the data. (This query below is generated by nhibernate.)

Will adding an order by clause (aka nHibernate sorting) help?

```
SELECT top 33 
 ... <field list> 
FROM 
  salesOrder this_ left outer join [Item] Item2_ on this_.ItemId=Item2_.ItemId 
WHERE this_.AccountId = @p0 
and this_.ModifiedAt > @p1 
and this_.ModifiedAt <= @p2
```

The database is **quite large**, but is not fragmented, and it performance is great. The problem has only been seen on very large tables (100 million rows) and even then only when the query returns > 1000 rows AND is paged.

Is an Order By clause (a sort at the nHibernate level) the solution, or is there another path we need to take?

Comment: @RadimKöhler We see paging work, in almost all cases... except when it does not. The issue is caused by large data sets on a large database. The question here is: How to make it %100 reliable?

Comment: You should *certainly* be ordering your result if you're paging. Otherwise, SQL server's behavior is undefined--it could return rows in any order.

Comment: @RadimKöhler OP revised

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker OP revised

Comment: @Jonesome: I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes," if you add an `OrderBy` clause you'll see all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: `ORDER BY` is required.

IOW, use a sort order (on an indexed field for best results!) on the nHibernate query.